# How to click a button with visible text (python selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser, click, visible

I am trying to click to a button which has a visible text but I can't find a way.[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl9K0.png)  . I am trying to click to the "laebel 41" but I need to click by detecting visible text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to click on the `label` element try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'41')]").click()
```

In order to click on `input` sibling element try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'41')]/..//input").click()
```

Don't forget to add some wait / delay before accessing the element to make it loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='41057']").click()
```

It is a radio button and if code doesn't work, you can search for radio button click

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='41']//ancestor::div/input[@type='radio']").click()

OR
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='41']/../input[@type='radio']").click()
```